# Repartitioning on kafka groupby

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to write a kafka streams application where all processing for a single key is done on a single server. This is guaranteed when the key does not change. However I want to do complex groupbys and split and recombine the data etc. All groupbys will only group data within the key (see below), therefore there is no need for a partition to communicate with another partition. The documentation says that any groupby will cause data to be written to a new topic, which presumably means it can be processed on a different server causing a delay. This is because groupby changes the key. Is there a way to avoid this? Is this something that kafka is not supposed to do and I should have a different strategy?

Example code:

```
        KTable<Integer, Integer> aggregateInput = inputStream
                .groupBy((key, integer) -> key*10 + integer%4)
                .aggregate(
                        ()->0,
                        (k,i,a)->a+i
                        );
        KTable<Integer, Integer> complexTransformation = aggregateInput.mapValues(v->v+1);
        KTable<Integer, Integer> regrouped = complexTransformation.groupBy(
                        (key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(key/10,value))
                .aggregate(
                        ()->0,
                        (k,i,a) -> a+i,
                        (k,i,a) -> a-i
                );
```

Note that the data is grouped by both the original key, and it's value mod 4, so there is no mixing of the original key. Additionally the final table has the same key as the original table due to the division by 10.

Thanks!